# Open source JavaScript interpreter written in Scala

Tags: javascript, scala, java

Is there any JavaScript interpreter written in Scala?

Comment: Does it really matter what language it was written in as long as it runs on the JVM?  Have you tried using [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)?

Comment: I'd like to see some Scala constructions in code

Comment: What do you mean by "Scala constructions in code"?

Comment: Using match { case }, parser class and so on... I'm still learning

Comment: The question you should be asking: How can I write a JavaScript parser in Scala?

Comment: @mikerobi that's only the right question after one has established that there is no good existing JavaScript parser in Scala.

Comment: @pelotom, look at his comments.  His goal is to understand parsing in Scala.  Studying the code of a full blown interpreter might not be the best way to go about that.

Comment: @mikerobi it's not clear to me that that's his goal... it sounded to me like he wanted to parse and interpret JavaScript first and foremost and have it be idiomatic Scala that he could learn from second. If this is purely a learning exercise, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing the actual code, the best thing to start with would probably be parser combinators: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-magic-behind-parser-combinators

Beyond that you'd need to then build the actual library along with the runtime code to take the parsed elements and execute them, which I'm afraid are out of my realm of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled), a PEG parser in scala.